# flutter_countdown_timer issue CurrentRemainingTime not recognized Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've a problem that I can't resolve I did a lot of research but nothing.
I need to use the library flutter_countdown_timer but he seems that CurrrentRemainingTime isnt recognized. Someone has already use this library ?
The error code is 'CurrentRemainingTime' isn't a type.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y8gc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you haven't imported the import statement for the CurrentRemainingTime. There are two import statements, one for CountDownTimer and the other for the CurrentRemainingTime.

Add this import statement:

```
import 'package:flutter_countdown_timer/current_remaining_time.dart';
```